# python 3, differences between two strings

Tags: string, python-3.x, difflib

I'd like to record the location of differences from both strings in a list (to remove them) ... preferably recording the highest separation point for each section, as these areas will have dynamic content.

**Compare these**

total chars 178. Two unique sections

```
t1 = 'WhereTisthetotalnumberofght5y5wsjhhhhjhkmhm Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentresultsduetodifferinglevelsofapxxxxxxxproximation,although'
```

and

total chars 211. Two unique sections

```
t2 = 'WhereTisthetotalnumberofdofodfgjnjndfgu><rgregw><sssssuguyguiygis>gggs<GS,Gs Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentrexxxxxxxsultsduetodifferinglevelsofapproximation,although'
```

I know **difflib** can do this but the output is bad.

I'd like to store (in a list) the char positions, perferably the larger seperation values.

**pattern location**

```
t1 = 'WhereTisthetotalnumberof  24  ght5y5wsjhhhhjhkmhm  43  Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentresultsduetodifferinglevelsofap  151  xxxxxxx  158  proximation,although'
t2 = 'WhereTisthetotalnumberof  24  dofodfgjnjndfgu><rgregw><sssssuguyguiygis>gggs<GS,Gs  76  Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentre  155  xxxxxxx  162  sultsduetodifferinglevelsofapproximation,although'
```

**output:**

```
output list = [24, 76, 151, 162]
```

**Update**

Response post @Olivier

position of all Y's seperated by ***

```
t1
WhereTisthetotalnumberofght5***y***5wsjhhhhjhkmhm Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentresultsduetodifferinglevelsofapxxxxxxxproximation,although

t2 WhereTisthetotalnumberofdofodfgjnjndfgu><rgregw><sssssugu***y***gui***y***gis>gggs<GS,Gs Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentrexxxxxxxsultsduetodifferinglevelsofapproximation,although
```

output after **matcher.get_matching_blocks()**
and `string = ''.join([t1[a:a+n] for a, _, n in blocks])`

```
WhereTisthetotalnumberof***y*** Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentresultsduetodifferinglevelsofapproximation,although
```

Comment: In addition to its subtraction and addition values placed beside the character .. It deals only in lists which is very slow. These strings will be large. 2000+ characters. But difflib examples are welcome for benchmarking purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `difflib` is probably your best bet as you are unlikely to come up with a more efficient solution than the algorithms it provides. What you want is to use `SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks`. Here is what it will output according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks).

> Return list of triples describing matching subsequences. Each triple
>   is of the form `(i, j, n)`, and means that `a[i:i+n] == b[j:j+n]`. The
>   triples are monotonically increasing in *i* and *j*.

Here is a way you could use this to reconstruct a string from which you removed the delta.

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

x = "abc_def"
y = "abc--ef"

matcher = SequenceMatcher(None, x, y)
blocks = matcher.get_matching_blocks()

# blocks: [Match(a=0, b=0, size=4), Match(a=5, b=5, size=2), Match(a=7, b=7, size=0)]

string = ''.join([x[a:a+n] for a, _, n in blocks])

# string: "abcef"
```

**Edit**: It was also pointed out that in a case where you had two strings like such.

```
t1 = 'WordWordaayaaWordWord'
t2 = 'WordWordbbbybWordWord'
```

Then the above code would return `'WordWordyWordWord`. This is because `get_matching_blocks` will catch that `'y'` that is present in both strings between the expected blocks. A solution around this is to filter the returned blocks by length.

```
string = ''.join([x[a:a+n] for a, _, n in blocks if n > 1])
```

If you want more complex analysis of the returned blocks you could also do the following.

```
def block_filter(substring):
    """Outputs True if the substring is to be merged, False otherwise"""
    ...


string = ''.join([x[a:a+n] for a, _, n in blocks if block_filter(x[a:a+n])])
```

Comment: thanks for this, looks promising, give me some a day or so and I'll get back to the post. Is this an estimation? ***string returns*** `WhereTisthetotalnumberofy  
  Thethreemethodsthatreturntheratioofmatchingtototalcharacterscangivedifferentresultsduetodifferinglevelsofapproximation,although`
the part `ofyThe` is incorrect

Comment: Could you reformat your previous comment, please? I do not really understand what you mean.

Comment: there is a character `y` after the first part `WhereTisthetotalnumberof` .. I'm not sure why its there.

Comment: Both `t1` and `t2` have a `'y'` between your expected first and second blocks. So as expected `get_matching_blocks` picks it up. If you provide aditional details about the expected behaviour in your question, it can be fixed. By example, we could filter out the blocks which matched less than a certain number of characters.

Comment: I've added a response post to the question to hopefully explain better