# Python 3, 2 strings as file argument to subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, stdin, popen

The subprocess calls [Diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/) which takes two files.

> Diff.exe 1.txt 2.txt

And returns the differences between them.

The following code works...

```
process = subprocess.Popen(relativePath1 + 'diff.exe ' + relativePath + '/1.txt ' + relativePath + '/2.txt', cwd=relativePath1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
print(process.stdout.read().decode())
```

I'd like to replace `relativePath + '/1.txt ' + relativePath + '/2.txt'` with strings instead of file destinations.

I found this similar post [Python string as file argument to subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334259/python-string-as-file-argument-to-subprocess) which takes in one argument ... but could not get this to work passing two strings to replace the two paths requested by diff.exe.

```
One = 'bla bla bal bla'.encode()
Two = 'bla xxx bal bla'.encode()

p = subprocess.Popen([relativePath1 + 'diff.exe'], shell=False, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=[subprocess.PIPE, subprocess.PIPE])
p.communicate(input=One, Two)
```

Comment: `diff`(`.exe`) requires two files as input: it can't diff two strings. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps the [difflib module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/difflib.html) can help you.

Comment: I had been suggested difflib here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737881/python-3-differences-between-two-strings ... and abandoned it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859026/python3-difflib-sequencematcher ... diffutils accomplishes this task with less mental stress. Thanks for commenting!

Comment: You are attempting to send two *strings* to an executable that takes two *filenames* as input; that is not the same. Why do you think that'll work?